# Accessing organizations in other enterprises

Tags: azure-devops

One of my customers added me to an Azure devops organization he created. When I try to access it through the 'Join now' link in the invitation email however, I get a message stating that 'An error has occurred. Contact your administrator for more information' (so not really informative).

If I check my profile information in Azure devops, I can see the organization url to which I was invited, but it is under the 'Organizations in Other Enterprises' section. And whichever tenant I choose in the dropdown on the right, the org I am trying to connect to stays under the 'Organizations in Other Enterprises' section.

Is there anything extra my customer needs to do to grant me access? He added another colleague of mine in exactly the same way as he did for me and for him it is working.

Comment: Is your e-mail address also registered as a Microsoft account? Might be that you're logged in to the MS account instead of the organizational one.

Comment: Can you share screenshots